# Flutter: How to handle NetworkImage with Invalid Image Data exception?

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

I am trying to use NetworkImage as the image in a BoxDecoration for a Container. The url passed to the NetworkImage will sometimes hold a bad image type (the url works and is correct but the actual image at the specified url is bad) resulting in an error.

To handle this occurrence I set up a method that uses a try-catch block where it returns the NetworkImage if successful, and a preset AssetImage in the event of an error. The try-catch block is not handling this exception, and throws an error instead of returning the AssetImage specified in the catch.

I've seen that Image.network has an onError parameter which looks like it would solve the problem, but Image.network is of type "Image" and BoxDecoration requires an "ImageProvider" (NetworkImage, AssetImage), so that does not help in this case.

Which is the best way to handle this error so that I can show an AssetImage in the case of the NetworkImage throwing an error?

Here is the Widget holding the BoxDecoration where I call the method I created to handle fetching the NetworkImage:

```
class CharacterPreviewCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final CharacterPreview character;
  const CharacterPreviewCard({Key? key, required this.character})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        context.router
            .push(CharacterDetailsRoute(characterId: character.characterId));
      },
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 171,
            width: 171,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
              color: Colors.black,
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: getCharacterAvatar(character.characterAvatarUrl),
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: smallMargin),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: smallMargin),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 165,
              child: Text(
                character.characterName,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Here is the method "getCharacterAvatar" which should return either NetworkImage or AssetImage:

```
ImageProvider<Object> getCharacterAvatar(String url) {
    try {
      final image = NetworkImage(url);
      return image;
    } catch (e) {
      return const AssetImage('assets/images/village-not-found-logo.png');
    }
  }
```

And here is the error in Debug Console:

```
The following _Exception was thrown resolving an image codec:
Exception: Invalid image data

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _futurize (dart:ui/painting.dart:5718:5)
#1      ImageDescriptor.encoded (dart:ui/painting.dart:5574:12)
#2      instantiateImageCodec (dart:ui/painting.dart:2056:60)
<asynchronous suspension>
Image provider: NetworkImage("https://narutoql.s3.amazonaws.com/Hana.jpg", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("https://narutoql.s3.amazonaws.com/Hana.jpg", scale: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to catch errors with `NetworkImage` or `Image.network`. More on this can be found here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20910.

Thanks to Tom3652's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73447581/flutter-how-to-handle-networkimage-with-invalid-image-data-exception/73448512?noredirect=1#comment129709424_73448512) suggesting the use of `CachedNetworkImage` I was able to find a solution that works using the Widget `CachedNetworkImage` with an `errorWidget` parameter to display an `AssetImage` when an error was thrown.

I replaced the `Container` that had the `NetworkImage` as a parameter for `DecorationImage` with a custom widget (to minimized code in the file). The custom widget returns the `CachedNetworkImage`.

Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
class PreviewCardImage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String url;
  final AssetImage errorImage;
  const PreviewCardImage({
    Key? key,
    required this.url,
    required this.errorImage,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CachedNetworkImage(
      imageUrl: url,
      imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
        height: 171,
        width: 171,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          color: Colors.black,
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: imageProvider,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      placeholder: (context, url) => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Container(
        height: 171,
        width: 171,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          color: Colors.black,
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: errorImage,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `Image.network` [class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html) replacing your `NetworkImage`.

It contains especially an `errorBuilder` parameter that allows you to set a custom widget in case of error :

```
Image.network(
  String src,
  {Key? key, 
  double scale = 1.0,
  ImageFrameBuilder? frameBuilder,
  ImageLoadingBuilder? loadingBuilder,
  ImageErrorWidgetBuilder? errorBuilder,
  ...
  int? cacheWidth,
  int? cacheHeight}
)
```

If you need the `ImageProvider`, then your method can look like this :

```
ImageProvider<Object> getCharacterAvatar(String url) {
     final image = Image.network(url, errorBuilder: (context, object, trace) {
      return Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/village-not-found-logo.png'));
    },).image;
     return image;
}
```

Please note the `.image` at the end of the `Image.network().image` to return the `ImageProvider`.

Comment: Appending `.image` to `Image.network` to return as an `ImageProvider` is awesome and I'll definitely be using this from now on when `ImageProvider` is required. Unfortunately, it looks like this "Invalid image data" exception is still not being caught by the `errorBuilder` and throws the exception without returning the `AssetImage`.

Comment: Oh i am sorry to hear that... Actually in my app i am using `CachedNetworkImage` from this package : https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image and the `errorBuilder` is called :) 
But if you don't want to cache the images i understand.

Comment: I found an issue (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20910) on Flutter's GitHub. It looks like there is no way to handle errors with either `NetworkImage` or `Image.network`, which is surprising given how essential these widgets are. The issue is marked as closed but there are about 30 comments under that saying it has not been solved. It looks like `CachedNetworkImage` will be able to handle the errors, so it makes sense why `errorBuilder` worked for you while using it. I'm going to go with that implementation. I appreciate the help!